# Converting to Excel "Date" format (within Excel file) using python and pandas from another date format from html table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am new to python and exploring to get data from excel using it and found pandas library to get data

I need to get the rates from a HTML table on a website. [Table from which the data has to be read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3M8z.png)
Then dump it in an excel file.
I am using Python
I have used the following code

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import lxml as lx
import openpyxl as oxl
url = "https://www.example.com"

tables = pd.read_html(url)
table = tables[0]
table.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

The dates are in dd mmm yyyy format in the 'Effective Date' column

I would like to convert them to the dd/mm/yyyy format

I used the following code to convert the table

```
['Effective Date'] = pd.to_datetime(table['Effective Date'],
                                        infer_datetime_format=False, format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='ignore')
```

but it fails to convert the dates in the column. Could someone head me in some proper direction please.

Here is the complete code

```
import pandas as pd
import html5lib
import datetime
import locale
import pytz
import lxml as lx
import openpyxl as oxl

url = "https://www.rba.gov.au/statistics/cash-rate/"

tables = pd.read_html(url)

table = tables[0]

table['Effective Date'] = pd.to_datetime(table['Effective Date'],
                                        infer_datetime_format=False, format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='ignore')

table.to_excel('rates.xlsx')
```

Comment: Use `['Effective Date'] = pd.to_datetime(table['Effective Date'], format='%d %b %Y', errors='ignore')` You need to pass the existing format of the date when converting to datetime, not the format you are looking to transform to. In excel, if the user has a UK locale set up on their computer, then the dates will be automatically converted when they open he excel file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DavidErickson, but this didnt help. In Excel, when i validate the date after exporting , the type of data is General for that category

Comment: please see my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `pd.ExcelWriter` to  create a `writer` object, so that you can change to Date format *WITHIN Excel*; however, this problem has a couple of different aspects to it:

1. You have non-date values in your date column, including "Legend:", "Cash rate decreased", "Cash Rate increased", and "Cash rate unchanged".
2. As mentioned in the comments, you must pass `format='%d %b %Y'` to `pd.to_datetime()` as that is the Date format you are converting FROM.
3. You must pass `errors='coerce'` in order to return `NaT` for those that don't meet the specified format
4. For the `pd.to_datetime()` line of code, you must add `.dt.date` at the end, because we use a `date_format` parameter and not a `datetime_format` parameter in creating the `writer` object later on. However, you could also exclude `dt.date` and change the format of the `datetime_format` parameter.
5. Then, do `table = table.dropna()` to drop rows with any columns with `NaT`
6. Pandas does not change the Date format WITHIN Excel. If you want to do that, then you should use `openpyxl` and create a `writer` object and pass the `date_format`. In case someone says this, you CANNOT simply do: `pd.to_datetime(table['Effective Date'], format='%d %b %Y', errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y')` or `.dt.strftime('%d/%m/%y')`, because that creates a "General" date format in EXCEL.
7. Output is ugly if you do not widen your columns, so I've included code for that as well. Please note that I am on a USA locale, so passing `d/m/yyyy` creates a "Custom" format in Excel.

**NOTE: In my code, I have to pass `m/d/yyyy` in order for a "Date" format to appear in EXCEL. You can simply change to `date_format='d/m/yyyy'` since my computer has a different locale than you (USA) that Excel utilizes for "Date" format.**

[Source + More on this topic](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_datetime.html):

---

```
import pandas as pd
import html5lib
import datetime
import locale
import pytz
import lxml as lx
import openpyxl as oxl

url = "https://www.rba.gov.au/statistics/cash-rate/"

tables = pd.read_html(url)

table = tables[0]

table['Effective Date'] = pd.to_datetime(table['Effective Date'], format='%d %b %Y', errors='coerce').dt.date
table = table.dropna()
table.to_excel('rates.xlsx')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("rates.xlsx",
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        date_format='m/d/yyyy')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects in order to set the column
# widths, to make the dates clearer.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet.set_column('B:E', 20)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, wow .... that's really awesome.. This really helped me a lot. To be honest, i am new to python and excel manipulations. Is there a way i can get better at doing this. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Also, if you dont mind, can you answer one more question.  This solved first half of my problem. There is another half of it.... If i have a datasheet with dates , can i compare the cash rates in this above example and apply the effective rates based on the dates whichever is highest ... basically copy this data from the website and put it into another excel sheet and before putting it , compare the value and then add it

Comment: Just keep practicing. `xlsxwriter`,  `openpyxl` and `xlwings` are good libraries for manipulation within excel files in terms of using excel features like widening columns, changing font size, inserting columns, formulas, etc. `pandas` is really for data wrangling and manipulation before the data gets to excel. But, if you want to use features within excel through python, then use  `xlsxwriter`,  `openpyxl` and/or `xlwings`.

Comment: @grumpypig please create a new StackOverFlow question. You can reference this question as a base. I'm sure someone will be able to help you. Feel free to comment back here when the new question is up, but I'm currently working on something else. Thank you!

Comment: @grumpypig no problem. Also kindly accept the answer as solution by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. I saw that you initially checked it, but then it got unchecked.

Comment: Please check now

Comment: Thank you, "you must add .dt.date at the end" was it for me. I would like to use different date formats ("dd.mm.yyyy" like "13.01.2093" and "mmm yyyy" like "Feb 2098") but that seems impossible with this solution. I settled on converting the "mmm yyyy" ones to strings, since it wasn't that important to keep them as dates.

Comment: @qubodup untested, but try `date_format='mmm yyyy'` or try `date_format='dd.mm.yyyy'`

Comment: @DavidErickson yeah, I used the dd.mm.yyyy one and it worked great but I couldn't figure out how to keep two columns as date format while one stays in one format and the other in another format.