# I just need Date, not time

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a small code to convert a number like 2022511 to 5/11/2022 in the ecxel file, but one problem is that it puts time next to it in the same way.
This is the code I wrote:

```
        result = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%Y.%-m.%-d')
        df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(result).dt.date
```

The output is like this:

[image]

How to remove time from it ?

Comment: Try removing .date in df['Date']

Comment: what is the output of `df['Date'].head().to_dict()`?

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/65405144/13361176?