# Why time format changes when write df to excel?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

When i try to write the df to one excel sheet the column with dates print with dates and time like 2007-01-02 00:00:00.
I want the date to stay with format 2007-01-02 (with NO time)
Why this happens?

I try in online Python interpeter and my terminal and was ok ...The problem is only when write to excel

```
import pandas as pd

player_list = [
    ['200712',50000], ['200714',51000], ['200716',51500],
    ['200719',53000], ['200721',54000],
    ['200724',55000], ['200729',57000]]
df = pd.DataFrame(player_list, columns=['Dates','Patients'])
print(df)
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'], format='%Y%m%d')
print(df)

title01 = 'test' + '_' + '.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(title01, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: This is Excel formatting the date as a date/time. Check if Excel has settings to control this.

Comment: The file does not have any preset. Manual cannot be the only solution. Besides, this is an example and there are many files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`.dt.date`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65402777/converting-to-excel-date-format-within-excel-file-using-python-and-pandas-fr) and write out to excel file

```
df['Dates'] = df['Dates'].dt.date
df.to_excel('title01.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! It works fine now...!!!!

Comment: perfect, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

> When i try to write the df to one excel sheet the column with dates print with dates and time like 2007-01-02 00:00:00

The reason this happens is that you are converting the strings to datetime objects (date + time) for which Pandas uses a default formatting of "`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`". So you can either convert the datetime column to a date column (as shown by @nisakova) or format the datetime output using the [pandas.ExcelWriter.datetime_format](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.datetime_format.html) option:

```py
import pandas as pd

player_list = [
    ["200712", 50000],
    ["200714", 51000],
    ["200716", 51500],
    ["200719", 53000],
    ["200721", 54000],
    ["200724", 55000],
    ["200729", 57000],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(player_list, columns=["Dates", "Patients"])
df["Dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Dates"], format="%Y%m%d")

title01 = "test" + "_" + ".xlsx"

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(title01,
                        engine="xlsxwriter",
                        datetime_format="yyyy-mm-dd")

df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name="sheet1")

writer.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!Your answer is very informative, detailed and complete...!!!!