How to convert object type column to datetime?
I have a decorator:
from typing import Union, List, Literal, Callable, Dict, TypeVar, ParamSpec
from functools import wraps
from pandas import DataFrame, ExcelWriter, NA, Series
from numpy import NaN


SaveFormatT = Literal['xlsx', 'csv', 'parquet']
F_Spec = ParamSpec('F_Spec')
F_Return = TypeVar('F_Return')


def save_to_file(
    filepath: str,
    date_columns: List[str] = None
) -> Callable[
    [Callable[F_Spec, F_Return]],
    Callable[F_Spec, F_Return]
]:

    def decorator(
        func: Callable[F_Spec, F_Return]
    ) -> Callable[F_Spec, F_Return]:
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args: F_Spec.args, **kwargs: F_Spec.kwargs) -> F_Return:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)

            file_format: SaveFormatT = kwargs.get('save_as')

            if file_format is None:
                return result

            def convert_timezones(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
                for column in df.select_dtypes(include=[
                     'datetime64[ns, UTC]',
                ]):
                    df[column] = df[column].dt.tz_convert(None)
                return df

            if isinstance(result, DataFrame):
                df, sheets = result, func.__name__
            elif isinstance(result, Dict):
                df, sheets = tuple(result.values()), tuple(result.keys())
                assert len(df) == len(sheets), f"""
        The number of sheets and the number of dataframes are different
        (Sheetlist: {len(sheets)}, df list: {len(df)}).
        The number of sheets and dataframes must match.
            """
            else:
                raise TypeError('Data with not supported format')
            df: DataFrame | Dict[str, DataFrame]
            sheets: str | List[str]
            try:
                if file_format == 'xlsx':
                    LOG.info('Save dataframe(s) to Excel')
                    with ExcelWriter(
                        filepath + '.xlsx',
                        mode='w',
                    ) as writer:
                        if isinstance(result, DataFrame):
                            result_xlsx = convert_timezones(result.copy())
                            result_xlsx.to_excel(
                                writer, sheet_name=sheets, index=False)
                        elif isinstance(result, Dict):
                            for frame, sheet in zip(df, sheets):
                                frame_xlsx = convert_timezones(frame.copy())
                                frame_xlsx.to_excel(
                                    writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=False)
    
            except PermissionError:
                print("""
        \033[91mHave no permission for write the file.
        Maybe file is open, you can't write the file while it's open.
        Close file and try again\033[0m
        """)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator

The mandatory condition for this decorator is that the input parameter is a DataFrame or Dict[str, DataFrame]. And I would like to simply specify it above any function if desired without worrying about an error. Such as:
>           raise ValueError(
                "Excel does not support datetimes with "
                "timezones. Please ensure that datetimes "
                "are timezone unaware before writing to Excel."
            )
E           ValueError: Excel does not support datetimes with timezones. Please ensure that datetimes are timezone unaware before writing to Excel.

However, some tables still have a problem with this decorator, there are tables where not all values ​​in the columns are of type datetime[ns, tz], such columns are simply of type object, how can these dates be determined and converted to a valid format and how can this be done without a loop?

Hi, check this thread, maybe it is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65402777/converting-to-excel-date-format-within-excel-file-using-python-and-pandas-fr

Also it will help if you can reduce your code example only to the crucial points. The question needs a minimal reproducible example, but yours code is a bit large given the question.

Despite the fact that @MaKruQ gave a good answer and @Johnny Cheesecutter
gave a good link, I still received an error for various tables related to the incompatibility of Excel and dates with the time zone. So I decided to rewrite the function as follows and it helped me.
def save_to_file(
    filepath: str,
    date_columns: str | List[str] = None  # add new optional parameter to specify column with object dtype and datetime\Timestamp type into it
) -> Callable[
    [Callable[F_Spec, F_Return]],
    Callable[F_Spec, F_Return]
]:
            def convert_timezones(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
                def convert(value):  # add function to check and replace tzinfo
                    if isinstance(value, Timestamp) and value.tz is not None:
                        return value.tz_convert(None)
                    elif isinstance(value, datetime):
                        return value.replace(tzinfo=None)
                    return value

                for column in df.select_dtypes(include=[
                    'datetime64[ns, UTC]',
                ]) + df[date_columns]:
                    df[column] = df[column].apply(convert)
                return df

It should be noted that my data had columns that contained None, and a date in a row, and a timestamp, and a datetime, and even a date like 0001-01-01 00:00:00+00:00. Changing the function solved the problem. But I still don't like to pass the date myself... although it's better than just looping through all the columns in the dataframe

Check for DataFrame or Dict[str, DataFrame]:
if not isinstance(result, (DataFrame, Dict)):
    raise ValueError("The result must be a DataFrame or a Dict[str, DataFrame]")

Convert to datetime: use pandas to_datetime:
import pandas as pd         
def convert_to_datetime(df: DataFrame, columns: List[str]) -> DataFrame:
                for column in columns:
                    df[column] = pd.to_datetime(df[column], errors='coerce')
                return df

